# Gradle error when integrating Google Calendar API and One Signal in Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-calendar, onesignal, google-calendar-api

I am working on an Android project where I am Integrating Google Calendar API and One Signal into the same project. The project already had OneSignal for notifications. Now I was following the google guidlines for integrating Google calendar API,[Here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android) . I am stuck at Step 4:a.I added the gradle 
dependencies into my gradle file, but now I am getting the error

```
Warning:Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305'. Resolved versions for app (1.3.9) and test app (2.0.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies'.
> Dependency Error. See console for details.
```

This is my current gradle file

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.icpdonline"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders=[onesignal_app_id: "b9389676-61e9-4622-a6f2-5b72e089c2ff",
        onesignal_google_project_number:"icpd-online-one-signal"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+"

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.2.1'
    compile( 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'){
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev234-1.22.0'){
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
}
```

The error is on the line

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'
```

when I hover the mouse over it, it is showing the error

```
    All com.google.android.gms libraries must use the exact same version 
specification(mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 
10.2.0,10.0.1.
```

I Understand What the error means, but I dont know how to fix it. I have tried adding versions to the end of gcm line, but to no avail. I cant seem to find the answer anywhere also. Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your Google Play Services libraries 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-xxx' should use the same version.

Change this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+"
```

To this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
```

Comment: In your apps build.gradle add  `android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}`. However, the original question was answered. To keep this clear for any future newcomers, instead of editing the original post with a different error, please create a new post with the new error.

Comment: Hey, that's exactly the error I. Thanks, now it's fixed with the fix u mentioned above. Can you spare the time to explain why that line fixed the error, it would be really helpful for future problems.

Comment: Sure, the above snippet forces the Gradle to compile the app and test app with the same version number. You could also  use 2.0.1 as the version number. Could you please mark the answer as solved? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
This answer by @drew solved the problem.
```

In your apps build.gradle add android { configurations.all { resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9' } }. However, the original question was answered. To keep this clear for any future newcomers, instead of editing the original post with a different error, please create a new post with the new error